# How to add yahoo users to my MSN list

Tags: windows-live-messenger

I tried to add a friend with yahoo account to my hotmail account msn. I followed the step. But my friend failed to show on my msn list. When I tried to add him again, it says "already added". But actually in fact he is nowhere on my list. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Contacts on Windows Live Messenger 2011 can be organized by 'Categories' or 'Online Status'. The contacts section of Live Messenger's options has this setting. (Screenshot 1)

If organized by 'Online Status', check if your Yahoo contact is not in the 'online' or 'offline' list/group. If organized by 'Categories', then the new contact will automatically go to the list/group 'Other Contacts'. Check here. (Screenshot 2)

If all else fails, simply type in a part of your contact's e-mail address in the search bar available with Live Messenger. The contact should now show up. (Screenshot3) On the context menu available from this contact, you should be able to move it into one of your more familiar lists/groups.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]